# Get searchView text when search button is clicked

Tags: android, android-studio, searchview

I'm new to android programming.

I have a problem with searchview. 
when I use textlistener, it ALWAYS checks the text while typing and not till user actually taps search in the search bar!

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.Search_View);
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                ///Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),query,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),newText,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        });
```

so when I type in searchbox, the message toasted letter by letter while I'm typing and not let me click on search on keyboard.

I searched a lot and couldn't find a solution.
Thanks for your solutions... :)

Comment: so basically you want the searched text when user hits the search button on keyboard??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SearchView is supposed to give users suggestion while typing. If you need to serch entire sentence or word consider using a EditText with a button instead of SearchView. Set listener to the button and start action (Toast the message) after user tap it.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that. thank you for your answer.

Comment: Glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get text when press button from `key board` then you use:

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), query, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return false;
}
```

`query` is your text where you want to use.

If you want get text with other button clicks like `Button`, `TextView` etc..

then you use like:

```
buttonname.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
       String query = searchView.getQuery();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try set method `onQueryTextChange(String newText)` empty body and return true if you do not want the search view to perform default action. Handle the input text yourself only in `onQueryTextSubmit(String query)`.